# Honda Odyssey 2021 Maintenance Manual

Tags: honda, odyssey, service-manual

I would like to get maintenance manual for Honda Odyssey 2021. I looked up online, there are available for older models, I also read that Honda stopped producing these manuals, so it will not be available anymore.

Is there any way to get it?
How would that car get fixed at the shop if there is no manual?

Comment: Dealers will have the manuals supplied for the computers they use to connect to the cars. They probably only stopped producing **printed** manuals...

Comment: Is the 2021 significantly different than earlier years?  In some cases they don't publish a new version if the model is the same.

Comment: Try Alldata or Mitchell online for service manuals. A subscription is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official Honda service manual online subscription: https://techinfo.honda.com/rjanisis/logon.aspx

1 day for $25, 30 days for $125, 365 days for $1250.

This is what the Honda dealership technicians will have. It will probably have the best explanations and diagrams.

I have read that this online system limits the number of downloads per time period now.

[People in the past have bought a one day subscription and downloaded everything for their car in PDF form](https://www.passportforums.com/threads/what-happened-to-service-manuals.4812/#post-40019).

The manuals that Honda stopped producing are the books such as my [2003 Honda Pilot service manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Psh.jpg)

---

[AllDataDIY](https://www.alldata.com/diy-us/en/find-vehicle) that people have mentioned does not have any 2021 Honda manuals at this time. Official Honda service manual would be preferred over this anyways. Independent shops probably have the shop version of AllData (note this is separate from AllData**DIY**) https://www.alldata.com/us/en/plp (see AllDataRepair)

---

[Haynes](https://haynes.com/en-us/) and [Chilton](https://www.chiltondiy.com/) manuals don't have any 2021 models at the moment. These are third party companies and I personally would prefer a OEM (Honda) service manual.